# Update the contents of Tkinter window

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, time, tkinter

I'm creating a Python program that displays the time and weather in a Tkinter window. I need to have the time, weather, and anything else constantly updating. Here's my old code:

```
import time

from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
while True:
    now = time.localtime(time.time()) # Fetch the time
    label = time.strftime("%I:%M", now) # Format it nicely
    # We'll add weather later once we find a source (urllib maybe?)
    w = Label(root, text=label) # Make our Tkinter label
    w.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

I've never done anything with Tkinter before, and it's frustrating that the loop doesn't work. Apparently, Tkinter doesn't let you do anything like loops or anything non-Tkinter while it's running. I thought I could maybe do something with threading.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


# Import anything we feel like importing
import threading
import time

# Thread for updating the date and weather
class TimeThread ( threading.Thread ):
    def run ( self ):
        while True:
            now = time.localtime(time.time()) # Get the time
            label = time.strftime("%I:%M", now) # Put it in a nice format
            global label # Make our label available to the TkinterThread class
            time.sleep(6)
            label = "Weather is unavailable." # We'll add in weather via urllib later.
            time.sleep(6)

# Thread for Tkinter UI
class TkinterThread ( threading.Thread ):
    def run ( self ):
        from Tkinter import * # Import Tkinter
        root = Tk() # Make our root widget
        w = Label(root, text=label) # Put our time and weather into a Tkinter label
        w.pack() # Pack our Tkinter window
        root.mainloop() # Make it go!

# Now that we've defined our threads, we can actually do something interesting.
TimeThread().start() # Start our time thread
while True:
    TkinterThread().start() # Start our Tkinter window
    TimeThread().start() # Update the time
    time.sleep(3) # Wait 3 seconds and update our Tkinter interface
```

So that doesn't work either. Multiple empty windows appear and they glitch out a ton. I get tons of errors in my debugger too.

Do I need to stop and re-open my window when I update? Can I tell Tkinter to update with something like `tkinter.update(root)` or something like that?

Is there a workaround or solution, or am I missing something? If you see anything wrong with my code, let me know.

Thanks!
Alex

Answer (score 1):

You can "nest" your `after` calls:

```
def update():
    now = time.localtime(time.time())
    label = time.strftime("%I:%M:%S", now)
    w.configure(text=label)
    root.after(1000, update)
```

Now you just have to call `after` once before the mainloop, and it updates every second from now on.

Comment: So I got this:

[link] (http://txt.do/o5we)

It keeps opening new blank windows every second. What am I missing here?

Comment: 1. You're creating a new `Tk` instance every time `update` is called. Move it outside the function as before. 2. You don't have to call `update` after you have started the main loop. 3. I didn't post the whole script, of course. I just gave you the method and some instructions how to implement your feature.